# Cannot connect to localhost:63342 when using matplotlib in PyCharm's Python scientific plotting

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm, anaconda

My PyCharm's scientific plotting mode doesn't work on localhost (not remote). It reports:

```
Error: failed to send plot to http://127.0.0.1:63342
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pycharm_display/datalore/display/display_.py", line 60, in _send_display_message
    urlopen(url, buffer)
  File "/Users/endaytrer/.conda/envs/NewProject/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Users/endaytrer/.conda/envs/NewProject/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/Users/endaytrer/.conda/envs/NewProject/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 542, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
  File "/Users/endaytrer/.conda/envs/NewProject/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Users/endaytrer/.conda/envs/NewProject/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1379, in http_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/Users/endaytrer/.conda/envs/NewProject/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1354, in do_open
    r = h.getresponse()
  File "/Users/endaytrer/.conda/envs/NewProject/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1332, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/Users/endaytrer/.conda/envs/NewProject/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 303, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/Users/endaytrer/.conda/envs/NewProject/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 272, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response
```

My matplotlib with the `show plots in tool window` in `Tools -> Python Scientific` unchecked (plot in original window instead of in SciView) worked normally.

Changing a few options such as debugging server's port and python's interpreter (anaconda3 (Python 3.7) and pure version of Python 3.8.3) does not help. I've also reinitialized a project, reinstalled PyCharm, reboot a couple of times, and reset all the settings in PyCharm, but the error still occurs.

I suppose that there is something wrong with my network configuration, but I do not know how to do.

System: macOS 10.15.3 (Hackintosh)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably caused by the HTTP proxy. Please check and delete if you have set the `http_proxy` in the environment variable.

Comment: could you explain more about your answer?

Comment: Alternatively, vote for this [known issue on jetbrain's issue tracking](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-39763)

Answer (score 1):

Wow just Simply Turned off my VPN and it solved my problem !
:D

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem on Windows platform. My OS version is win10 1909 and used the latest PyCharm Professional 2020.2.2.，reinstalling this version didn't solve the problem.

1. So first I used [Jetbrain ToolBox](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/) and downgraded PyCharm to 2019.3.5 version.
   The Error disappeared, but matplotlib could not show any figure in SciView.
2. Then I installed PyCharm Professional **2020.1.4**, the problem fixed and everything worked well.
3. Since different versions of PyCharm can work at the same time，I found the output figure of **2020.2.2** version can be shown normally in the **2020.1.4** SciView Plot area, so weird...

Considering that you are using macOS, I don't know if this information is useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem on Windows platform. To adress this problem, I upgraded my Pycharm program, I used the **2020.1.1** and I got the **2020.1.5**, It works perfectly.

To update the program, you can go to **Settings/Appearance & Behavior/Updates** section or use the **Jetbrains Toolkit**.

Greetings.

Answer (score -3):

Could you please do the following:

1.Add `PYCHARM_DEBUG=True` environment variable to your run/debug configuration

2.Reproduce the issue

3.Provide the full output from the console.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO!  it is preferred to ask for clarification in the comments. Answers are reserved for answers.